# C# Why do I get a 'The relationship could not be changed' exception? (EF)

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have this method:

```
    public void AddFile(MediaFileName mediaFile)
    {
        // Get a list of items which must be removed
        var tmp = MediaFileNames.ToList().Where(m => m.FileName.Contains(mediaFile.FileType.ToString())).ToList(); // FileType is an enum

        // remove each item from the Navigation property from memory
        tmp.ForEach(f => MediaFileNames.Remove(f));

        // Store items with an id in a list. This list is accessed by the presenter to delete these records
        tmp.Where(f => f.Id != 0).ToList().ForEach(f => _filesToRemove.Add(f));

        // Set the items filename
        mediaFile.FileName = mediaFile.FileType.ToString() + new FileInfo(mediaFile.SourceFile).Extension;

        // Add the item to the navigation property 
        MediaFileNames.Add(mediaFile);
    }
```

MediaFilesNames is a navigation property of the class Media.

I keep a list (_filesToRemove) of items which has to be removed from the database. This list is accessed from my repository:

```
    public bool Update(Act act)
    {
        foreach (var file in act.Media.FilesToRemove)
        {
            if (_context.MediaFileNames.FirstOrDefault(f => file.Id == f.Id) != null)
                _context.MediaFileNames.DeleteObject(file);
        }

        _context.SaveChanges();

        return true;
    }
```

When SaveChanges is called I get this message:

`The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.`

I don't get why I get this message, because I am deleting existing items and I am only adding one new item. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the relationships in your database, and specify that their delete rules must be done in cascade mode.

Or, try to check your foreign keys in the tables that are concerned, and set their ALLOW NULL value to true. What you can do is use indexes for the incriminated columns and add unique constraint on them, so that you can use them as foreign key in your relationships.

If the column is part of the primary key, you won't be able to set ALLOW NULL to true.